# Registering generic type with multiple constructors

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector, cachemanager

I am trying to move from Unity to Simple Injector and having trouble getting the Injection to work with Simple Injector.

Working Unity code is below

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

container.RegisterType(
    typeof(ICacheManager<>),
    new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
    new InjectionFactory((c, targetType, name) =>
        CacheFactory.FromConfiguration(targetType.GenericTypeArguments[0], "myCache")));
```

My Attempts:

```
var registration = Lifestyle.Singleton.CreateRegistration(
    typeof(ICacheManager<>),
    typeof(BaseCacheManager<>), 
    container);

container.AddRegistration(
    serviceType: typeof(BaseCacheManager<>),
    registration: registration);
```

I am getting the following error

> For the container to be able to create `BaseCacheManager<Object>` it should have only one public constructor

Comment: You should make sure the type only has one constructor. Remove the other constructors.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Steve, I am using an external library from CacheManager.net to help with caching. Any other alternatives, other than removing the second constructor?

Comment: Can't you use a DI framework which can handle that? Even the new lightweight MS (dotnet core) thing can deal with it. It is a pretty big restriction to allow only one public ctor on a class ~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can solve this in Simple Injector.

First of all, always let your components have a single constructor, since having [multiple constructors is an anti-pattern](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97).

Since however the supplied type is from an external library, it is impossible for you to change it.

What you can do instead is derive from this particular type and create a sub class that only has one constructor. This type can call into the specific constructor of the base class you are interested in:

```
class MyBaseClassManager<T> : BaseCacheManager<T>
{
    public MyBaseClassManager([args]) : base([args]) { }
}

container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ICacheManager<>), typeof(MyBaseCacheManager<>)):
```

In general however, you should prevent having your application code depend on abstractions that are not defined by the application, since this is a [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) (DIP) violation. The DIP guides us into defining application-tailored abstractions. Based on such abstraction you can define an adapter that forwards the call to the external component. Example:

```
// In the application's core layer
public interface ICache<T>
{
}

// Adapter in the Composition Root
public sealed class CacheManagerCacheAdapter<T> : ICache<T>
{
    private static BaseCacheManager<T> manager = new BaseCacheManager<T>();

    // Implement ICache<T> methods
    public object GetByKey(object key)
    {
        // translate and forward to the external component
        return this.manager[key];
    }
}

// Registration
container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(ICache<>), typeof(CacheManagerCacheAdapter<>)):
```

If the number of closed types you need is limited, you can also register every closed version explicitly:

```
container.RegisterSingleton<ICacheManager<Foo>>(new BaseCacheManager<Foo>());    
container.RegisterSingleton<ICacheManager<Bar>>(new BaseCacheManager<Bar>());    
container.RegisterSingleton<ICacheManager<FooBar>>(new BaseCacheManager<FooBar>());
```

Yet another option is to override Constructor Resolution Behavior, as explained [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensibility.html#overriding-constructor-resolution-behavior). You can do this

```
public class CacheManagerConstructorResolutionBehavior 
    : IConstructorResolutionBehavior {
    private readonly IConstructorResolutionBehavior org;
    public CacheManagerConstructorResolutionBehavior(IConstructorResolutionBehavior org) {
        this.org = org;
    }
    public ConstructorInfo GetConstructor(Type serviceType, Type implementationType) {
        if (implementationType.IsGenericType && 
            implementationType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseCacheManager<>)) {
            return implementationType.GetConstructors()
                .OrderByDescending(c => c.GetParameters().Length)
                .First();
        }
        return this.org.GetConstructor(serviceType, implementationType);
    }
}

var container = new Container();
container.Options.ConstructorResolutionBehavior =
    new CacheManagerConstructorResolutionBehavior(
        container.Options.ConstructorResolutionBehavior);
```

Yet another option is to hook onto the [ResolveUnregisteredType` event](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensibility.html#resolving-unregistered-types) although I would only advise this as last resort.

Comment: Thank you Steven, I really appreciate the time you have taken to answer this question. Since the CacheManager library is violating the DIP, I started looking into other implementations and found this https://github.com/exceptionless/Foundatio#caching.

Comment: Hi @WebbyWebDeveloper. That library isn't violating the DIP; your application is. Your application can use any library, but the DIP guides us into hiding those libraries from the application's main code.

Comment: Just a side note: BaseCacheManager will have only one ctor in the next version of the library. I changed it a few days ago, actually funny this comes up right now ;)
Apart from that, in general, I totally disagree with having multiple ctor being an issue. You'll always have to deal with 3rd party libraries and a DI framework should never put such constraints on you. Luckily there are many of those frameworks, and you can just pick another one ^^

Comment: @MichaC: Please read [the referenced article](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97). I clearly state that this doesn't concern library builders. It's absolutely fine that you have multiple constructors on your reusable library classes; Application components however, should *only* have one single constructor.

Comment: @Steven - Thank you for educating me. I had to read the referenced article and your sample code multiple times to fully understand it.

Comment: @MichaC: To get a better picture of my view, you should also read [this comment of mine](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/pull/101#issuecomment-246206384).